# High voltage anode electron gun

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

In the image it can be seen that the anode voltage of a SEM field emission electron gun is up to 30kV.
I think that at that voltage an electric arc can occur between the electrons and the anode, or am I wrong?

Or is the distance between the electron beam and the anode large enough that the arc does not occur?

Or is the exit velocity of the first anode (due to field emission) high enough not to hit the anode?

[image]

Comment: There is a vacuum inside the microscope so there cannot be an arc.

Comment: There are electric arcs in a vacuum, an example of this is field emission.

Comment: Without the focusing, yes, electrons would hit the anode. I would not call that an arc exactly. But 30kV isn't all that much. Vacuum breakdown between clean surfaces requires >150 kV/cm of field, and can be much higher depending on the exact surfaces.

Comment: As an aside, I'm currently involved in designing an electron source with 2MV between the cathode and anode, and, yes, we don't want the beam to hit the anode so we focus it.

Comment: @JonCuster How do you focus?

Comment: Magnets and field shaping.

Comment: @JonCuster I can not imagine what kind of magnetic field would be needed if there were 2 MV within the electron gun. Isn't the whole cathode+anode assembly all at relatively similar floating negative voltage, and the ≈2MV are against the earth? (Because in a typical Wehnelt design, there is < 1kV voltage difference around the filament although the accelerating voltage can be e.g. 30kV)

Comment: @dominecf - the cathode will be -1MV and the anode at +1MV relative to ground. As a pulsed power driven electron source, it is not a "typical" design.